# Allowing a user to access a library - SharePoint OnLine

Tags: sharepoint-online

On a site, I want to invite a user to edit in a library, but without having access to other libraries/lists on the site. 
- I stop the inheritance of the library rights and then invite the user and give him modification rights.

The problem is that his only way to access the library is to use the direct link (sharing link) to that library. But he can't go to the home page of the site and then access the library.

Answer (score 1):

That is true, that is how it will work... When you break inheritance of library, user will get access to library and just limited access to site. this limited access is provided so that user can go till library path.

Now if you want that user to access home page, you can break permission of library where home page is located and provide item level permission to that page...then that user will be able to browse home page. Add a content editor web part of home page with library link and apply target audience to only visible to that user....

Hope this helps...!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
So there is no way for the user to enter the site and find the library in the left column?

Comment: For that you will need to grant the use access to the site (or more specifically, the page in question).  Your original requirement states “without the user having access to other libraries/lists on the site.  This includes the Pages library.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the page library! :D 
So I allowed the user to access this library. But there is no navigation bar on the left....

Answer (score 0):

After many tests, I finally found a solution to allow a user to access a site library, without accessing the files of other libraries on the site, while being able to navigate the site and therefore access it without necessarily having a direct link to the library.

The solution is a little complex to implement the first time, but it works:
- Break the inheritance and invite the user to the target library.
- Break the inheritance on the library of pages of the site and invite the user (collaboration/reading).
- Add a new level of access to the site (e. g. "limited reading") and invite all users with access to only one particular library in that level of access.

This authorization level must be set up with the following authorizations:
- Open - Allow users to open a website,...
- Use the features...
- Use remote interfaces...
- Browse user information...
- Show pages...
- Browse directories
- Apply themes and borders...

The user will then be able to access the desired library, browse the entire site, enter the site through the home page, may not be able to view the content of other libraries / lists.